# 'Left' and 'Right' CSS not working

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website (not a real one, just for practise).

At the top I am having a long bar in which the title will go, and that is fine. Below this I want two smaller boxes and each side (on the same row).

There should be a gap in the middle which is below the title box and in-between the two smaller boxes.

I have attempted to make this using 'left' and 'right' percentages, with each box only coming in 25% on it's respective side, leaving a 50% gap in the middle. When

I launch this code it has the title bar OK, but then one long bar taking up 75% of the screen below it, instead of what I wanted.

Please help but try and explain simply since I am a 12 year old that has only recently started coding! Below you can see the code...

See the snippet

---

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://res.freestockphotos.biz/pictures/8/8990-close-up-of-a-green-hedge-pv.jpg");
}

#backgroundbox {
  width: 100% position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #66ff66;
  border: 15px solid #00cc00;
}

#navl {
  background-color: #66ff66;
  border: 15px solid #00cc00;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.6%;
  right: 25%;
  height: 75px;
}

#navr {
  background-color: #66ff66;
  border: 15px solid #00cc00;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 75%;
  right: 99.4%;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="backgroundbox"></div>
  <div id="navl"></div>
  <div id="navr"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be easy to solve with `float` left and right and then decide the `width` of each box
[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/q0uedrqy/) where I removed your `position` `left` and `right` properties

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://res.freestockphotos.biz/pictures/8/8990-close-up-of-a-green-hedge-pv.jpg");
  }
  
  #backgroundbox {
  width: 100%
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #66ff66;
  border: 15px solid #00cc00;
  }

  #navl {
  background-color: #66ff66;
  border: 15px solid #00cc00;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  float: left;
  height: 75px;
  width: 25%;
  }
  
  #navr{
  background-color: #66ff66;
  border: 15px solid #00cc00;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  float: right;
  height: 75px;
  width: 25%;
  }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="backgroundbox"></div>
<div id="navl"></div><div id="navr"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are very welcome. We only learn by asking and making mistakes. At 12 it's impressive that you are here at all. Keep going, and good luck. And don't forget, if this answer worked for you, you should select it as the right answer (green tick on the left next to the up/down vote arrows

Answer (score 0):

You are not an idiot, you are just learning, we all started somewhere. I still am in the dark about anything other than CSS so...

Anyway, you are specifying your positioning in %, which will only work if the height and width of the parent container is specified previously.
Try specifying the body's width and height to 100% or better still, create a container div, nest all other divs inside it and specify this container div to be 100% in both height and width. Also, you have a semicolon missing after the width specification of the #backgroundbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got a solution for you:

**Try it:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>ASGD</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://i.imgur.com/Ug8Tx59.png">
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url("http://res.freestockphotos.biz/pictures/8/8990-close-up-of-a-green-hedge-pv.jpg");
        }

        #backgroundbox {
            width: 100% position: absolute;
            margin: auto;
            height: 150px;
            background-color: #66ff66;
            border: 15px solid #00cc00;
        }

        #navl {
            background-color: #66ff66;
            border: 15px solid #00cc00;
            border-top-width: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0.6%;
            height: 75px;
            width: 100px;
        }

        #navr {
            background-color: #66ff66;
            border: 15px solid #00cc00;
            border-top-width: 15px;
            border-top-width: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0.6%;
            height: 75px;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="backgroundbox"></div>
    <div id="navl"></div>
    <div id="navr"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the preview link: https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/zPYgZa